# How to rdirect to some another page on another website using IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, downtime

I have a website which is used by a number of users, when we tried to update some new changes it always has some downtime. Now i want to display a page which is hosted on some other server or domain using IIS settings, is it possible. I know i can do it by using app_offline.htm page, but i don't want to use the manual process. is there any setting on iis by using which i can redirect website to that page when website is suffering for downtime.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have an extra IIS site configured on the same server, bound to the same domain and port. That extra site is normally stopped. When you want to do maintenance you can stop your main site and start that extra site instead.

But that is mostly just an awkward workaround for functionality that is already available in using app_offline.htm.

Comment: So what you want is something that automatically detects that your site is down and redirects the traffic?